# Getting an error "No token to close. Path ''." from JsonWriter (NewtonSoft.Json 13.0.1)

Tags: c#, json.net

The following code sample:

```
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    writer.WritePropertyName("client_id");
    writer.WriteValue(_clientID);
    writer.WritePropertyName("client_secret");
    writer.WriteValue(_clientSecret);
    writer.WritePropertyName("audience");
    writer.WriteValue(_audience);
    writer.WritePropertyName("grant_type");
    writer.WriteValue(_grantType);
    writer.WriteEnd();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}

Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
```

Fails with the message `No token to close. Path ''.`

[image: No token to close path]

What am I doing wrong?  I was not able to find an answer through Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The problem is you are attempting to close the object twice:

```
writer.WriteEnd();
writer.WriteEndObject();
```

Remove one of these lines to fix the problem.  You don't need both.

---

**More detailed explanation:**

Calls to `WriteStartObject` and `WriteStartArray` must be balanced with a corresponding call to `WriteEndObject` and `WriteEndArray`.

`WriteEnd` is a convenience method that closes the last token, whatever type it happens to be.  So it functions the same as `WriteEndObject` and `WriteEndArray`.

In your code you call `WriteStartObject` once at the beginning of the method but then you call *both* `WriteEnd` and `WriteEndObject` to end it.  The first of these closes the object you started; the second throws an exception because there's nothing to close-- you already closed it.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer! Could I ask, would you recommend I stick to NewtonSoft or the .net5 system.text.json ?

Comment: That depends entirely on your situation.  Do you have a reason to switch?  Newtonsoft has much more functionality than System.Text.Json at this time and has been around for longer.  System.Json.Text has different goals than Newtonsoft.  Specifically, it aims for higher throughput via support for `Span<T>` and is more strict in parsing.  Does that matter?  I don't know.  You'll need to do your own research and make a decision.  If there's no good reason to switch, stick with what you have.